# Mule JMX agent - Need to update port value at runtime

Tags: spring, mule

I am using a spring property 'port', but the value of this port variable changes dynamically when the application is running and I want to access this new dynamic value everytime its value changes. But I am getting an exception at startup when using the configuration below.

```
<custom-agent name="jolokia-agent" class="org.jolokia.mule.JolokiaMuleAgent">
    <spring:property name="port" value="#[app.registry.appConf.port]"</spring:property>
</custom-agent>
```

appConf is a Spring Bean.

Snippet of the error:

```
10/31/12 15:18:44.244 ERROR [main] DefaultMuleApplication - null
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[app.registry.appConf.port]"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:528)
    at java.lang.Integer.decode(Integer.java:958)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.j    ava:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.ja    va:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:4    06)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.ja    va:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:510)
```

The application started when I changed the value attribute to a Spring Expression
    **value="#{appConf.port}"**
but the value is not getting updated at runtime.

I need to change this value at run-time. How can this be achevied?

Answer (score 1):

Just inject the `appConf` POJO in `jolokia-agent`.

That way you can call `getPort()` on it at runtime.

Comment: jolokia-agent is a third party library (jolokia.org) which I am using in my application. I cannot update the jolokia-agent code to inject appConf into it. Can you please help me with some other alternative or lemme know if I got you wrong?

Comment: Mmmh: does Jolokia support port change at runtime? If yes, you could try to get a hold of the agent instance either by finding it in the Mule registry or in the MBeanServer, then try setting a different port and (potentially) re-initializing the agent.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I will follow this approach and update you if it works.

Comment: @jai did you have any success with this approach?